# modify cells in previous sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I've been stuck on this one.

I am building a home made cells locking system.
A part of this system wants a variant range of cells to be locked when the user
goes from one sheet 
to another.

That range is like ("A1:K"& lowerLimit).  Some sheets have few lines, some go as far as 9000.

I created a first template sheet, then gave a name to the range and finally copied that sheet. So I don't have an issue pointing at that specific range. For each sheet.

The issue is I want (when the user goes from one sheet to another) to automatically have the previous sheets named range to lock. I went for a solution that leads to endless cycles, it was two variants that followed track of the ActiveSheet and the previous, Made it trigger with `Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)`. Does not work since the previous sheet becomes the ActiveSheet and goes on.

I find it weird that `Private Sub Workbook_SheetDeActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)` triggers after ActiveSheet changes, or is it that I just don't get it.

Is there a way to unlock sheet, lock cells, then re-lock sheet. For specific sheet (would be the last ActiveSheet) without activating that sheet?

And if impossible, do you think there is a way around my sloppy method?

Thank you.

Comment: use `Application.EnableEvents = False` in the beggining of event and `Application.EnableEvents = True` and the end of event code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the activesheet does change before the deactivate event. Doesnt make sense to me either.

but use the activate event or deactivate event of sheets. The deactivate happens before the activate happens.

have global variables, and put code in each sheets deactivate (or activate) that takes the currently saved active sheet, and makes that previous, and then in the new active sheet put activesheet.name:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
    Previoussheet = gActiveSheet 'currently held gactivesheet variable represents the previously active sheet (as it hasnt been changed yet.
    gActivesheet = Activesheet.name 'save the currently active sheet in active sheet

End Sub
```

and you can accuratly compare the previous and currently active sheets, and you can lock / unlock as needed.